# Советы по проектированию БД

Tags: база-данных, mysql

Проектирую БД приемной комиссий, вот что получилось:

[image]

У меня остались без внешних ключей такие поля как: `id_школьный_язык, id_специальность`. подскажите как правильно связать эти поля? Думаю, в таблице spr_language создать поле код и связать ее с полем `id_школьный_язык`, а `id_специальность` связать с полем код, правильно ли я думаю? Вообще правильно ли я проектирую бд?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну id_школьный_язык по факту можно связать с spr_language по факту если я правильно понимаю это просто ID языка обучения и ID языка желаемого обучения.

Связал так (я вероятнее всего в чем-то не прав, но по моей логике, должно быть так):
[image]

Comment: Quiss
спасибо понятно, скажите пожалуйста название графического генератора бд.

Comment: DB Forge Studio MySQL.
Там и строение запросов, и визуальное строение... =)
http://www.devart.com/ru/dbforge/mysql/studio/